# How do you keep logins organized between multiple developers?

Tags: security, organization, permissions, access

I've worked at several places with 2-10 developers and each place has struggled in the area of tracking if the company has an account on a given web site or service.  We're always left wondering...

- What's the username
- What's the password (Obviously you don't want to store this, I'm not looking for something that does)
- What's the account number
- Who created this
- When was it created
- What email is our account registered under

**What do you guys use to track this kind of thing between multiple developers?**  I've setup at least a dozen accounts for the company I currently work for and I don't have any documentation to show the next guy what's been done.

Ideally I'm looking for a web solution that will be locked down within our VPN.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like a spreadsheet on a shared drive?

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but you should also be aware of risk management issues with having shared accounts and put the appropriate controls in place. What happens when a developer leaves the company? Where are the account details stored and how are they accessed? Can you restrict access once it is given? What if you are hacked?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt - I'm hoping for a web based solution so it can be apart of our developer intranet.

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia - Security is definitely a concern here.  That's why I don't want to store any passwords, but just usernames and a recovery email address and other generic non-threatening data

Answer (score 4):

Our admins use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) to keep track of accounts on 3rd party sites and server passwords.

KeePass is a Windows app which stores user names and passwords (and optionally a lot of additional info) in an encrypted database. You just need one master password to open the database and view the content.

---

**EDIT:**

I just read that you're looking for a web-based solution.

As I said before, KeePass is a desktop app (not web-based), but there is also a portable version *(available on the [download page](http://keepass.info/download.html))*.
I'm using this at home to share a single KeePass installation across all my machines: the portable version is on my NAS drive, and from each machine I start KeePass directly from the NAS.

Note: This works for **me**. I'm the only user and I never used KeePass from more than one machine at once. And I don't know what happens when you try it!
You could try it - if it works, maybe putting the portable version on a network share and just linking that from your intranet is an option for you.

Comment: KeePass is cross platform

Comment: Okay,maybe I should have made this more clear: there **are** versions for other operating systems besides Windows, but these seem to be unofficial. The [download page](http://keepass.info/download.html) as well the [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePass) say this, that's why I wrote that KeePass is a Windows app.

Comment: Sorry, I got it confused with KeePassX

Comment: We use KeePass in our small development team, and it works pretty well; it supports multiple databases so if you have different levels of access you could create multiple database files, each with their own master access password. We sync databases w/ SVN, so that's another potential layer of security (i.e. repository access).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MindTouch

We use Mindtouch but any sort wiki solution would do the trick. You could also set up a lastpass account to which the whole team has access and store all the per account info in secure notes. You could leave out the passwords if you don't trust that and change the account password when a team member moves on.

We use Mindtouch for a lot of things but a subpage dedicated to webservice accounts is one obvious application.

Answer (score 0):

If they're accounts that the business relies on or pays for, there should be someone who's designated as responsible for managing that account. This is important not just for keeping track of whatever information is in the account, but also for making sure that it gets renewed when that's necessary. Ideally, the same person is responsible for managing all the accounts in this category.

If they're not accounts that the business relies on or pays for, it shouldn't much matter if you lose access to it when someone leaves.

> I've setup at least a dozen accounts for the company I currently work
>   for and I don't have any documentation to show the next guy what's
>   been done.

Why don't you? Even a simple text file, spreadsheet, or internal web page would be a good start -- you don't need an elaborate database to manage the few scraps of information needed for each account. Forget about the next guy -- if the company relies on it, you should have it organized so that *you* can keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at something like [Secret Server](http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html) -- it was a product originally built by a development shop to solve this sort of problem and it is also a wonderful password safe program on the side.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some kind of personal wiki (like TiddlyWiki) when an issue arises... copy/pasta the question and appropriate answers into the wiki and store on a local server/development box. Then if you have issues and no outside internet access, you'll still have a (sort of) solution for when problems arise. Additionally, you can put accompanying info that might not be releasable to the public as well as links to other intranet locations/sites.

To answer the question though: developers should use their own accounts for the information. Anything relevant to the domain/work area should just be stored locally rather than the "cloud"